# Expression Tree of logical expression

Tags: data-structures, tree, logic

I need to transform this: `(a < b)∧(b < c)∨(c < d)`
expression into an expression tree, but I can't figure out a way that looks correct. Here is what I got:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm predicting this will be a long answer, because I will go through the general thinking process for achieving a solution. For the inpatient, the solution is at the end.

**Is your solution correct?**

Well, it depends. Your picture would be totally correct if `∨` took precedence over `∧`, in which case you would need to apply `∧` only after `(b < c) ∨ (c < d)` has a result. It would also be correct if you forced precedence using parenthesis like so:

```
(a < b) ∧ ( (b < c) ∨ (c < d) )
```

That said, when talking about [operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), typically `∧/and` has precedence over `∨/or`. When precedence is the same, the evaluation happens from left to right, meaning the right side depends on the result of the left side.

> The highest the precedence of an operator, the lower it appears in the tree.

The rest of the answer will assume the usual operator precedence.

**How to approach this problem?**

The best approach to this sort of problems is to decompose the expression. Even better, if we decompose using the [prefix/polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation), it will be more natural to build up the tree later.

Given: `(a < b) ∧ (b < c) ∨ (c < d)`

Let's decompose it into parts:

```
x = (a < b), which translates to prefix: < a b
y = (b < c), which translates to prefix: < b c
z = (c < d), which translates to prefix: < c d
```

We now have 3 inequality expressions decomposed as `x`, `y` and `z`.

Now to the logical operators.

```
i = x ∧ y, which translates to prefix: ∧ x y
j = i ∨ z, which translates to prefix: ∨ i z
```

We now have 2 logical expressions decomposed as `i` and `j`. Note how they depend on `x`, `y`, `z`. But also, that `j` depends on `i`. Dependencies are important because you know tree leaves have no dependencies.

**How to build the tree?**

To sum up, this is what we decomposed from the original expression:

```
x = < a b
y = < b c
z = < c d
i = ∧ x y
j = ∨ i z
```

Let's approach it bottom-up.

Considering the dependencies, the leaves are obviously the most independent elements: `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`.

Let's build the bottom of the tree considering all appearances of these independent elements in the decomposition we just made (`b` and `c` appear twice, we put them twice).

```
a   b   b   c   c   d
```

Now let's build `x`, `y` and `z` which depends only on `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. I'll be using `/` and `\` for building my ASCII art as equivalent to your picture lines.

```
  x       y       z
  <       <       <
 / \     / \     / \
a   b   b   c   c   d
```

Now as we've seen, `i` depends only on x and y. So we can put it there now. We can't add `j` just yet, because we need `i` to be there first.

```
      i
      ∧
    /   \
  x       y       z
  <       <       <
 / \     / \     / \
a   b   b   c   c   d
```

Now we are just missing `j`, which depends on `i` and `z`.

```
           j
           ∨
         /   \      
        /     \
      i        \
      ∧         \
   /     \       \
  x       y       z
  <       <       <
 / \     / \     / \
a   b   b   c   c   d
```

And we have a full expression tree. As you see, each dependency level will result in a tree level.

To be completely accurate, a [Breadth-First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) in this tree would have to consider that `z` is on the same level of `i`, so the correct representation of the tree would have to put `z` one level higher:

```
            j
            ∨
         /     \      
        /       \
      i          z
      ∧          <
   /     \      / \
  x       y    c   d
  <       <       
 / \     / \     
a   b   b   c
```

Just one more note, for it to be completely clear, for the expression `(a < b) ∧ ( (b < c) ∨ (c < d) )`, the decomposition result would be:

```
x = < a b
y = < b c
z = < c d
j = ∨ y z
i = ∧ x j
```

Which would, in turn, result in the tree in your picture.

Hope this helps your future endeavours on building expression trees.

Comment: Thank you for that in-depth explanation, this helped me a lot. Only one thing, yesterday I asked my tutor if I can use the same variable multiple times in the tree and he didnt really have an answer and told me to just not do it. I can`t figure out a way to not use b and c twice, so is he wrong or am i missing something?

Comment: The short answer is yes. But there's a difference between a variable and a tree node. When building a tree, you can't share a tree node between two parent nodes, that would make it a graph and not a tree. This does not say anything about what a leaf tree node contains inside it. A leaf tree node may hold, for example, a value (`123`, `"foo"`) or a reference to a variable (`a`, `b`). When evaluating the tree, if a tree node with a variable is found, the lookup of the actual value of the variable is done in some other structure, external to the tree.